# Speed up wheel scroll based event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I have a custom script which advances a small icon upon wheel scroll. It works well but it's not advancing the element as quickly as I would like. I'd like to increase the distance that the element (pill) moves per wheel scroll. How can I alter the code to facilitate this? Thanks for any insight. Code:

```
function wheel(e) {
var modelContentWrapper = $('.model-content-wrapper');
var howModelWorks_steps = $('#howModelWorks_steps');

var currentIndex = $('.model-content.active', modelContentWrapper).index();
var $pill = $('.step_' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' > a.clickable-icon');
var $li = $('ul.steps li');
var $pillStep = ($li.width()) / wheelSpeed;
direction = 'right';
if ((e.wheelDelta && e.wheelDelta >= 0) || (e.detail && e.detail < 0)) {
    wheelValue++;
    if ((firstElement && parseInt($pill.css('margin-left')) > initialIconLeft) || (!firstElement)) {
        $pill.css('margin-left', (parseInt($pill.css('margin-left')) - $pillStep) + 'rem');
    }
    if (wheelValue >= wheelSpeed) {
        wheelValue = wheelValue - wheelSpeed;
        forceModelBackward();
    }
    //direction = 'left';
}
else {
    wheelValue--;
    //direction = 'right';
    if (!lastElement) {
        $pill.css('margin-left', (parseInt($pill.css('margin-left')) + $pillStep) + 'rem');
    }
    if (Math.abs(wheelValue) == wheelSpeed) {
        wheelValue = wheelValue + wheelSpeed;
        forceModelForward();
    }
}


//if (wheelValue > (wheelSpeed * 5) || wheelValue < (wheelSpeed * -5)) {
if (stepsCounter == 1 || stepsCounter == 4) {
    enableScroll();
}
preventDefault(e);
}
```

Comment: Do you understand your own code?

Comment: I'm assuming wheel gets called as part of a scroll event?

Comment: Probably want to include the forceModelBackward() and forceModelForward() functions.

Comment: Have you tried decreasing wheelSpeed? If it's already at 1, you could make wheelValue++ or wheelValue-- change by two instead to double the speed. In the 2nd case, you would definitely want to change the line `if(Math.abs(wheelValue) == wheelSpeed)` to `if(Math.abs(wheelValue) >= wheelSpeed)`

Comment: Right. I will try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the follow to your event listener..

capture: true,
passive: true

Passive Event Listeners allow you to attach un-cancelable handlers to events, letting browsers optimize around your event listeners. The browser can then, for example, keep scrolling at native speed without waiting for your event handlers to finish executing.

Usage

Probably what is used mostly:

```
    // Really, if you're using wheel, you should instead be using the 'scroll' event,
    // as it's passive by default.
    document.addEventListener('wheel', (evt) => {
      // ... do stuff with evt
    }, true)
```

You’ll need to replace it with this:

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', (evt) => {
  // ... do stuff with evt
}, {
  capture: true,
  passive: true
})
```

Copied information from [alligator dot io](https://alligator.io/js/speed-up-scroll-events/)